# Compare two files in two different folders and replace it by the newer

Tags: vbscript

With this VBScript code I was able to copy files. If the file exists it does nothing, if not it will copy the files needed.

```
Dim Photo
SourceFolder = "C:\Photo1"
DistinationFolder = "C:\Photo2"
Set ObjPhoto = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each Photo In ObjPhoto.GetFolder( SourceFolder).Files
    If Not ObjPhoto.FileExists(ObjPhoto.BuildPath(DistinationFolder, Replace(Photo.Name, ".jpg", ".bmp"))) Then
        photo.Copy ObjPhoto.BuildPath(DistinationFolder, Photo.Name), True
    End If
Next
```

I want to compare the files if the source files also exists in the destination folder and replace it by the newer.

Comment: visit following forum hope this will help: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?621051-Compare-files-in-two-folders

Answer (score 1):

If you want to overwrite based on the last modified date, then the `File` object has the property you want: `DateLastModified`. (You can check all properties of the `File` object [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ft05taf(v=vs.84).aspx).)

You already have access to the source file objects (your code's `Photo` variable) so you just need to get the target's file object.

Something like this should work:

```
Dim Photo
Dim targetFile, bmpTargetFilename, jpgTargetFilename

SourceFolder = "C:\Photo1"
DistinationFolder = "C:\Photo2"

Set ObjPhoto = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each Photo In ObjPhoto.GetFolder(SourceFolder).Files
    bmpTargetFilename = ObjPhoto.BuildPath(DistinationFolder, Replace(Photo.Name, ".jpg", ".bmp"))
    jpgTargetFilename = ObjPhoto.BuildPath(DistinationFolder, Photo.Name)

    If ObjPhoto.FileExists(bmpTargetFilename) Then
        ' Get the target file object
        Set targetFile = ObjPhoto.GetFile(jpgTargetFilename)
        ' Now compare the last modified dates of both files
        If Photo.DateLastModified > targetFile.DateLastModified Then
            Photo.Copy jpgTargetFilename, True
        End If
    Else
        Photo.Copy jpgTargetFilename, True
    End If
Next
```

A couple of notes:

- It seems you are checking for the existence of a .BMP file yet copying a .JPG file, so I made it explicit by using two variables.
- I am also assuming you want to compare the JPG files, since those are the ones being copied.